# Set custom referer

Tags: referer

just for the purpose of study, I see that some sites offer services that allow the user to change the referrer for custom links. Services like spoofr and hitleap for example allow the User to define a particular access such as the twiiter.com domain, facebook.com, pinterest or even a custom domain.

Again I say, it is a curiosity that came to me and not for other purposes. My question is as follows:

How could this sites change referer to make fake referer?

I do not need scripts or other information, I just want to know how they do it in textual form.

Answer (score 1):

> How could this sites change referer to make fake referer?

By acting as a proxy. When a request is sent through that website/service, the service then constructs a new HTTP request (with all the HTTP request headers, include the "fake" referer - which is normally sent by the browser) which is then sent to the target website. The response is received and sent back to the client.

You can do this yourself by using a program like CURL to send an HTTP request.

There are no doubt browser extensions that also allow you to do this. To either suppress the HTTP referer altogether or to set it so something of your choice.